# Find Paragraph tags but not those inside blockquote using PHP

Tags: php

I want to insert ad code after the 2nd paragraph but excluding paragraphs that are inside a blockquote tag.

Example html

```
<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis odio ac dolor semper porta. Vestibulum dapibus est elit, dictum tristique tellus elementum eget. Pellentesque ligula arcu, aliquet et blandit eget, luctus at neque. Phasellus suscipit nibh neque, gravida vulputate diam congue id.</p> 

<blockquote><p>Suspendisse eleifend nisl vitae odio elementum fermentum. Phasellus elementum commodo tincidunt.</p></blockquote>

<p>Fusce lobortis magna eu erat mattis aliquet eu non sem. Donec dapibus mattis consequat.</p>
</section>
```

I was trying to do this with DOM but I have never worked with DOM. I was able to get all of the paragraphs but was not sure how to check if the paragraph exists inside of a blockquote tag.

Comment: DOM is the right way. You should learn using it. Query for all "p" nodes, fetch the xpath from that node, and check if "blockquote" is inside the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$html = '<section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis odio ac dolor semper porta. Vestibulum dapibus est elit, dictum tristique tellus elementum eget. Pellentesque ligula arcu, aliquet et blandit eget, luctus at neque. Phasellus suscipit nibh neque, gravida vulputate diam congue id.</p> 

<blockquote><p>Suspendisse eleifend nisl vitae odio elementum fermentum. Phasellus elementum commodo tincidunt.</p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Suspendisse eleifend nisl vitae odio elementum fermentum. Phasellus elementum commodo tincidunt.</p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Suspendisse eleifend nisl vitae odio elementum fermentum. Phasellus elementum commodo tincidunt.</p></blockquote>

<p>Fusce lobortis magna eu erat mattis aliquet eu non sem. Donec dapibus mattis consequat.</p>
<p>Fusce lobortis magna eu erat mattis aliquet eu non sem. Donec dapibus mattis consequat.</p>
<p>Fusce lobortis magna eu erat mattis aliquet eu non sem. Donec dapibus mattis consequat.</p>
</section>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->createElement('div','this is newly created div and append after second paragraph');
$dom->getElementsByTagName('section')->item(0)->childNodes->item(1)->appendChild($div); 
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```